# Image not showing from JSON URL in Ionic Apps

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic apps.Here below is the code of my controller:

```
.controller('AreaListCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$sce', '$state', 'JsonResponseFactory', 'Loader',
function ($scope, $location, $sce, $state, JsonResponseFactory, Loader) {
    Loader.showLoading('Loading Area List ...');

    var data = [
                   { "Id": 0, "Name": "Gulsan", "ImageUrl": "http://admin-panel.studynovels.com/ContentImages/food_area_sample_1.jpg", "NumberOfRestaurants": 5 },
                   { "Id": 1, "Name": "Banani", "ImageUrl": "http://admin-panel.studynovels.com/ContentImages/food_area_sample_1.jpg", "NumberOfRestaurants": 4 },
                   { "Id": 2, "Name": "Dhanmondi", "ImageUrl": "http://admin-panel.studynovels.com/ContentImages/food_area_sample_1.jpg", "NumberOfRestaurants": 4 },
                   { "Id": 3, "Name": "Uttra", "ImageUrl": "http://admin-panel.studynovels.com/ContentImages/food_area_sample_1.jpg", "NumberOfRestaurants": 2 }
               ];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i].ImageUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(data[i].ImageUrl);
    }

    $scope.userName = 'Ahmed All Razi';
    $scope.areaList = data;
    Loader.hideLoading();
}
])
```

And the code for my page is:

```
<ion-content>
    <div class="text-center" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">
        <br />
        <h4 ng-show="userName">Hello, {{::userName}}</h4>
        <h6>Thank you for visiting our app. Please select your area from the list.</h6>
        <br />
    </div>

    <a class="card item" ng-repeat="area in areaList" ng-href="#/restaurantList/{{::area.Id}}">
        <h2 ng-show="area.Name">{{::area.Name}}</h2>
        <img ng-show="area.ImageUrl" ng-src="area.ImageUrl" />
        <hr />
        <h4 ng-show="area.NumberOfRestaurants">Total Restaurants {{::area.NumberOfRestaurants}}</h4>
    </a>
    <br />
</ion-content>
```

Every field is loading fine but image is not showing on page.

I am getting the follwing output
[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvuLD.png)

[Note]:

1. I have added the whitelist plugin 
   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
2. Added following line in my config.xml
3. Added the following meta tag into my index.html

Can anyone help me to render the images properly on page.

Comment: Press F12 to go into developer tools, reload the page, watch the console for errors, also Inspect the <img> element and see if it points to the right URL in the src attribute.

Comment: I am getting an "404 not found" error for the images because the request has been sent to "http://localhost:8100/area.ImageUrl". How to load the image from the original url?

Comment: first test it by printing the value to html element then put it to src tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.
I added the following meta tag in my index.html which blocked the images to loading from external sources:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' mythicangel.com">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https:">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' https://cordova.apache.org">
```

I just removed that line and image is loading now.
Thanks everyone for responding.

Comment: Well, it also wouldn't have worked unless you specified {{area.ImageUrl}} so I would appreciate if you tick my answer as accepted :)

Comment: yes offcourse ... i forgot to mention ... thank you once again ... and I am sorry that I do not have enough point to give you a '+1' ...

Comment: Sorry I mean can you tick my answer, I don't think you get points for ticking your own anyway. But that's fine if you wish to leave this one as ticked.

Answer (score 2):

You must use:

```
<img ng-show="area.ImageUrl" ng-src="{{area.ImageUrl}}" />
```

in your declaration (note the use of parenthesis, for more information read up on the ngSrc directive https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).

Comment: Hi, I tried this {{area.ImageUrl}} but it didn't work and in this case the blank thumbnail is not showing on my pages.

Comment: It should work, what does the src value say in inspecting the element now?

Comment: always use angular loop angularforEach loop with angular related stuff  . while you are iterating objects angular for each is finer option than for loop .. it should load img as per GONeale answer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach